# Manipulating Index and Small Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I currently have a formula set in place which does an index on a few rows, if it contains a value, it will show the values name, otherwise it won't show anything. The value in this example is in the M column. If the M column doesn't contain a value of -1, then show the name which is located in column L. This functionality works fine as shown below:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Results!$L$2:Results!$L$8,SMALL(IF(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8<>-1,ROW(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8)-1),ROW()-13)),"")}
```

I'd like to add onto this formula so that if there are any extra empty index values not being used, it will index again on another range for items that contain values to contribute to the group(Results Col A and B). The only issue with my tested example is that if the rows overlap, it shows cell M's name over cell A's name. How could I correct this formula to add under the rows instead of overlapping?

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Results!$L$2:Results!$L$8,SMALL(IF(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8<>-1,ROW(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8)-1),ROW()-13)),IFERROR(INDEX(Results!$A$2:Results!$A$8,SMALL(IF(Results!$B$2:Results!$B$8<>-1,ROW(Results!$B$2:Results!$B$8)-1),ROW()-13)),""))}
```

### Results:

```
Col A       Col B ..............Col L       Col M
name1        -1                1name          9
name2        -1                2name          5 
name3        2                 3name          7
name4        -1                4name          -1
name5        -1                5name          -1
```

### How display looks(overlapping):

```
Usernames with value <> -1:
1name
2name
3name
```

### How display should look(no overlapping)

```
Usernames with value <> -1:
1name
2name
3name
name3
```

To fix the overlap I would need to adjust the Row()-13 portion to skip the rows that have values. By doing this I would need to check the count of non-empty cells and add them to 13 to not overwrite. However it doesn't work. Why?

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Results!$L$2:Results!$L$8,SMALL(IF(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8<>-1,ROW(Results!$M$2:Results!$M$8)-1),ROW()-13)),IFERROR(INDEX(Results!$A$2:Results!$A$8,SMALL(IF(Results!$B$2:Results!$B$8<>-1,ROW(Results!$B$2:Results!$B$8)-1),ROW()-(COUNTA(A14:A19)+13))),""))}
```

However it works when in a cell individualy. It seems it doesn't like that I add within the subtraciton of ROW().

```
=COUNTA(A14:A19)+13
```